# ImportError: No Module Named Shell; shell not imported (32-bit, python)

Tags: python, shell, 32-bit, py2exe, importerror

I'm working on a project in python with many different python files and extra libraries that have to be installed, and I'm currently trying to compile a 32-bit version (we currently only have a 64-bit .exe).

However, though everything works perfectly when running the regular python file, when running the compiled .exe (compiled with py2exe), I keep getting the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "fredchat.py", line 23, in <module>
    File "fcio.pyc", line 20, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named shell
```

fredchat.py has, as expected, an

```
 import fcio
```

command at line 23. However, nowhere in fcio.py is the word "shell" even mentioned!

Our setup.py is pretty much exactly the basic:

```
 from distutils.core import setup
 import py2exe

 setup(console=['fredchat.py'])
```

Unfortunately I can't give any of the actual code, A. because it's long, and B. because the project leader is quite restrictive (understandably) about what code we give out when.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `import fcio` instead of `import fcio.py`?

Comment: Erm, yes. Thank-you, my apologies for that stupid mistake. >.<

Comment: Was your .pyc file generated from the 64-bit Python?  Try removing all the .pyc files then run it again.

Comment: line 20 of fcio is completely blank; I tried removing the .pyc files but it's still problematic. Is there a way to force it to include the shell module in the py2exe setup.py, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is a known issue with py2exe and win32com. [The py2exe wiki](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/win32com.shell) has a workaround. Insert the following code near the start of your setup.py file. This will trick py2exe into looking for the `win32com.shell` modules and including it in the distribution.

```
# ...
# ModuleFinder can't handle runtime changes to __path__, but win32com uses them
try:
    # py2exe 0.6.4 introduced a replacement modulefinder.
    # This means we have to add package paths there, not to the built-in
    # one.  If this new modulefinder gets integrated into Python, then
    # we might be able to revert this some day.
    # if this doesn't work, try import modulefinder
    try:
        import py2exe.mf as modulefinder
    except ImportError:
        import modulefinder
    import win32com, sys
    for p in win32com.__path__[1:]:
        modulefinder.AddPackagePath("win32com", p)
    for extra in ["win32com.shell"]: #,"win32com.mapi"
        __import__(extra)
        m = sys.modules[extra]
        for p in m.__path__[1:]:
            modulefinder.AddPackagePath(extra, p)
except ImportError:
    # no build path setup, no worries.
    pass

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# ...
# The rest of the setup file.
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the offending module is being imported dynamically and py2exe doesn't recognize it when assembling the dependencies. You can try to import that module directly in your code and create a new executable. Other possibility is to force py2exe to include the module adding the following to your config:

```
opts = {
  'py2exe': { "includes" : ["qualified_module_name"] }
}
```